# My assembly "quiz Multiply" code is not working?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, emu8086

this is my assembly code . it not working ..
I tried to write it in another way but it gives me other mistakes
I use emu8086..... in first page there will be 3 pages (1,2,3) and you have to choose which 
page.

1- study 2-exam 3-exit

1. study: will learn Multiplication table from 0-9
2. exam: questions about mult from 0-9
3. exit from the quiz

and after finish quiz there will be mark.

```
multi-segment executable file template.

data segment                                      
    firstpage db "welcome to learn  math ",10,13,"create by:saad ",10,13,"1.study",10,13,"2.exam",10,13,"3.exit" ,10,13,"$"
    q1 db "2*1=$"
    q2 db "2*2=$"
    q3 db "2*3=$"
    q4 db "2*4=$"
    q5  db "2*5=$"  
  std1 db "2*1=1 $"
  std2 db "2*2=4 $"
  std3 db "2*3=6 $"
  std4 db "2*4=8 $"
  std5 db "2*5=10 $"
  nl    db ,10,13,"$"
  mark0 db "your mark us:0 $"
  mark1 db "your mark us:20 $"
  mark2 db "your mark us:40 $"
  mark3 db "your mark us:60 $"
  mark4 db "your mark us:80 $"
  mark5 db "your mark us:100 $"
count db 0
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:

    mov ax, data
    mov dx, ax                                                          
    lea dx, firstpage
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h          
    mov ah,7
    int 21h  
    cmp al,3
    je t1


    t1: mov ax,3
    int 21h
    lea dx,std1
    int 21h
    mov ah,7
    int 21h
    lea dx ,nl
    mov ah,9
    int 21h    
       lea dx,std2
    int 21h
    mov ah,7
    int 21h
    lea dx ,nl
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
       lea dx,std3
    int 21h
    mov ah,7
    int 21h
    lea dx ,nl
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
       lea dx,std4
    int 21h
    mov ah,7
    int 21h
    lea dx ,nl
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
       lea dx,std5
    int 21h
    mov ah,7
    int 21h
    lea dx ,nl
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    mov ah,7
    int 21h
    lea dx ,q1
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    lea dx ,nl
    mov ah ,9
    int 21h
     lea dx ,q2
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    lea dx ,nl
    mov ah ,9
    int 21h
     lea dx ,q3
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    lea dx ,nl
    mov ah ,9
    int 21h
     lea dx ,q4
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    lea dx ,nl
    mov ah ,9
    int 21h
     lea dx ,q5
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    lea dx ,nl
    mov ah ,9
    int 21h
    mov ah,1
    int 21h
    cmp count,0
    je mark0
    cmp count,1
    je mark1
    cmp count, 2
    je mark2
     cmp count,3
    je mark3
     cmp count,4
    je mark4
     cmp count,5
    je mark5

      mark0:lea dx,mark0
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    jmp soof
      mark1:lea dx,mark1
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    jmp soof
      mark2:lea dx,mark2
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    jmp soof
      mark3:lea dx,mark3
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    jmp soof
      mark4:lea dx,mark4
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    jmp soof
      mark5:lea dx,mark5
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    jmp soof









    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h    
ends

end start
```

Comment: "not working at all" is not a good problem description. Also, use your emulator to single step the code and see why it is failing.

Comment: @Jester Not exactly what I mean, but it needs modification ..

Answer (score 3):

### A list of errors:

> ```
> nl    db ,10,13,"$"
> ```

The extra comma translates to an extra zero. What you get is `db 0,10,13,"$"`

---

> ```
> mov ax, data
> mov dx, ax
> ```

To setup the segment registers you need to write:

```
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax      ; Do read carefully: DS
```

---

> ```
> mov ah,7
> int 21h  
> cmp al,3
> je t1
> ```

When the user presses the key labeled "3", you will receive the code 51 in `AL`.
Your check therefore should be `cmp al, 51` or better `cmp al, '3'`.

---

> ```
> t1: mov ax,3      <<<<<< This sets AH=0
> int 21h
> lea dx,std1
> int 21h
> mov ah,7
> int 21h
> ```

Since `AH=0` is a ProgramExit function, none of the code that follows will get executed.

---

> ```
> mov ah,7
> int 21h
> ```

Your program contains lots of these and you don't use the result from `AL`. If these are your debugging efforts, you should have removed them **before** posting on this forum. Now this is very confusing for anyone who reads your program.